# How do you write a call in one method (functionA) to a method (functionB) in another class (Category1) that receives no parameters?

Tags: java

How do you write a call in one method (functionA) to a method (functionB) in another class (Category1) that receives no parameters?

Hi, this is a question from the class, and I am trying to understand the question and solve it, but having a hard time. I tried to read books and searched webs to figure it out.

And this is what I just wrote.. However, I just have no idea if it is right or even close.

```
public void addFunctionB (Category1 Category1, String functionB) {
    Category1.setFunctionB(functionB);
}
```

Comment: I don't even understand the question at all =\

Comment: That is a very badly worded question. Which method receives no parameters? functionA or functionB? however your answer cannot be correct as in your example code both methods have parameters.

Comment: Do you want to call a function that is present in class A, from a function that is in class B?

Comment: I think it is asking to write a call in a method called function A to a method called function B in Category1 class..? I am confused..though

Comment: In that case, if the function is not static you need to create an instance of the class in which the method to be called is present and then call that method. If it is not a static function you can call it without creating an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this what you're looking for.

```
public void functionA(){ // Function A which calls Function B
    Category1 category1 = new Category1(); // Creating an instance of Category1 which has the function B
    category1.functionB(); // Using the instance created above to call the method functionB
}
```

Your FunctionB could be `static` as well, so in that case, you won't need to instantiate Category1 to call it. You could directly call it like this

```
Category1.functionB(); // Calling the method statically.
```

Comment: Thank you! but why is c of second category1 in second line in lower case? and category1 in third line as well?

Comment: @user2822147  you have to read alot dude. first one is reference and second is static invokation. Search for Static methods in java.

Comment: @user2822147  you are welcome.Please mark this post as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
public void main
(
     public static functionB()
    ()
)

class Category1
{
    public static functionA()
    (
    main.functionB();
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do you write a call in one method (functionA) to a method (functionB) in another class (Category1) that receives no parameters?

## Using dot operator ??

Simple by creating/or receiving that  `instance`

One way  creating `instance`.

```
public void functionA(){ 
    Category1 category1 = new Category1();
    category1.functionB();
}
```

other way receiving instance.

```
public void functionA(Category1 category1){ 
    category1.functionB();
}
```